# Visual studio how to recover a combobox SelectedValuePath which values come from an enum?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

I have a comboBox which values are defined in an enum.
The code in WPF is :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Statuts}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding StatutSelectionne, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The codes in ViewModel are :

```
public Dictionary<object, string> Statuts
    {
        get { return typeof(StatutType).GetDictionary(); }
    }


private int _statutSelectionne;
    public virtual int StatutSelectionne
    {
        get { return _statutSelectionne; }
        set
        {
            _statutSelectionne = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The other codes in C# are :

```
[Description("Statuts")]
public enum StatutType
{
    [Description("Statut A")]
    StatutA,
    [Description("Statut B")]
    StatutB,
    [Description("Statut C")]
    StatutC,
    [Description("Statut D")]
    StatutD,
}

public static Dictionary<object, string> GetDictionary(this Type enumType, EnumDescriptionType descriptionType = EnumDescriptionType.withoutEnumtypeDescription)
    {
        if (enumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumType");
        if (enumType.IsEnum == false)
            throw new ArgumentException("enumValue must be an Enum.");
        var dico = new Dictionary<object, string>();
        var lst = enumType.GetEnumValues();
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            dico.Add(item, item.GetEnumValueDescription(descriptionType));
        }
        return dico;
    }
```

My problem is when I choose in the comboBox, the value of StatutSelectionne doesn’t change.
For example, if I choose “Statut C” in the combobox, StatutSelectionne should be equal at 2.
I specify that in the database, the data type of “Statut” is Int.
I don’t know where my mistake is.
(English isn’t my native language)

Comment: Can you please post other part of your code like EnumDescriptionType , GetEnumValueDescription etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code for GetValueEnumDescription is in C# :

```
public static string GetEnumValueDescription(this object enumValue, EnumDescriptionType descriptionType = EnumDescriptionType.withEnumTypeDescriptionAtt)
    {
        if (enumValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumValue");

        var enumType = enumValue.GetType();

        if (enumValue.GetType().IsEnum == false)
            throw new ArgumentException("enumValue must be an Enum.");

        var fieldInfo = enumType.GetField(enumValue.ToString());
        var customAttributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        var attribute = customAttributes.FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

        string att = attribute != null ? attribute.Description : enumValue.ToString();

        switch (descriptionType)
        {
            case EnumDescriptionType.withEnumTypeDescriptionAtt:
                if (enumType.EnumTypeDescriptionExist())
                    return $"{enumType.GetEnumTypeDescription()} {att}";
                else
                    return att;
            case EnumDescriptionType.withEnumTypeDescription:
                return $"{enumType.GetEnumTypeDescription()} {att}";
            case EnumDescriptionType.withoutEnumtypeDescription:
            default:
                return att;
        }
    }
```

and the code for EnumDescriptionType in C# is :

```
[Description("Type d'affichage")]
public enum EnumDescriptionType
{
    [Description("sans description du type de l'enum")]
    withoutEnumtypeDescription,

    [Description("avec description du type de l'enum si un attribut description est présent")]
    withEnumTypeDescriptionAtt,

    [Description("avec description du type de l'enum même si un attribut description n'est présent")]
    withEnumTypeDescription
}
```